# How to join a column of same values to another different table in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this table structure for names_table:

| Name | Age | Gender |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Someone1 | 25 | Male |
| Someone2 | 25 | Female |

Another table names_with_company has this structure:

| CompanyID | Name | Age | Gender |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |

Now, I want to copy the data from names_table by adding a single value to column of CompanyID.

Expected result:

| CompanyID | Name | Age | Gender |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | Someone1 | 25 | Male |
| 1234 | Someone2 | 25 | Female |

I am quite confused what should I include.

```
INSERT INTO names_with_company 
'1234',SELECT * FROM names_table
```

or

```
INSERT INTO names_with_company 
SELECT * FROM (
'1234'
UNION
SELECT * FROM names_table
)
```

These two doesn't work

I know these two tables are two different structures, but is there any way to have a static value in column and rest of the data from another table?

Also, can you please not suggest creating another table and joining them? I prefer it to be done using the above code lines, but with a working logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get into the habbit of always specifying the column names:

```
INSERT INTO names_with_company (CompanyID, Name, Age, Gender)
SELECT 1234, Name, Age, Gender
FROM names_table;
```

As you can see, you can provide "literal" values for any column.

Comment: I'm learning SQL and working on different concepts. Thanks for making it simple, I'll keep your advice in mind.

Answer (score 0):

you can not able to insert because your 1st query

```
INSERT INTO names_with_company 
'1234',SELECT * FROM names_table
```

is completely wrong but if you written like below

```
INSERT INTO names_with_company 
SELECT '1234',name,age,gender FROM names_table
```

it will work
but it is always better to mention the column name explicitly which is given in another answer by @stu

your 2nd query also wrong cause for union operation you have to provider same number of columns for all the selection

```
INSERT INTO names_with_company 
SELECT * FROM (
'1234'
UNION
SELECT * FROM names_table
)
```

but you have  used only one select

write method for union operation is like below

```
select col1,col2 from table1
union

select col1,col2 from table2
```

then you can use it any other way